# Read Secretkey from JCEKS keystore | Java

Tags: java, keystore, jks, secret-key, jceks

I am trying to read secret key (passphrase) from JCEKS keystore using Java code , code is working for JKS keystore but not for JCEKS keystore. i am using ibm_sdk71 as runtime (due to project requirements).

```
public static String getPasswordFromKeystore(String entry, String keystoreLocation, String keyStorePassword,String keyPP1) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, java.security.UnrecoverableEntryException{
    char[] password = "new".toCharArray() ;  
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(keystoreLocation);
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection keyPP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyPP1.toCharArray());
    KeyStore ks= KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
    ks.load(fIn, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBE");
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske;
    ske = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)ks.getEntry(entry, keyPP);
    PBEKeySpec keySpec;
    keySpec = (PBEKeySpec)factory.getKeySpec(ske.getSecretKey(),PBEKeySpec.class);
    password = keySpec.getPassword();
  return new String(password);
}
```

Appreciate any guidance.
Regards

Comment: Can you try this solution please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744181/export-secret-key-from-jck-key-store

Comment: Figured out , as i am using IBMJDK , PBE is replaced with PBEWithMD5AndDES in below code 
  SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");

but now i am stuck while getting keySpecification as i am using PBEkeySpec.class